# How to check for openCV on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opencv

How can I confirm if openCV is properly installed in my computer ? Is there any quick command line for it ? I am on Ubuntu 9.10

Comment: did you check the `path` variable? Also, are you on linux? Windows? OSX? something else?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

A proper answer to my own question !

> pkg-config --modversion opencv

Comment: I just installed 2.4.3 but still this command states opencv 2.0 any idea why? Do i need to restart or something?

Comment: @Hans Wassink Not sure, but I get a 2.4.2 ! may be a restart is needed !

Comment: this command returns `2.x.x` but I have neither the include files, nor the files mentioned by Sunny under `/usr/local/lib`. So this might not be the correct answer

Comment: ```Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found``` , Ubuntu 16

Answer (score 10):

**With OpenCV 2.4.x:**

You can use "CV_VERSION" or "CV_MAJOR_VERSION", "CV_MINOR_VERSION", "CV_SUBMINOR_VERSION" from a C/C++ simple program.

Example of 'main.c':

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\r\n", CV_VERSION);
    printf("%u.%u.%u\r\n", CV_MAJOR_VERSION, CV_MINOR_VERSION, CV_SUBMINOR_VERSION);
}
```

Here is the compilation line:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` main.c `pkg-config --libs opencv` -o main
```

Comment: this is c++ program ( g++)

Answer (score 8):

Here's an easy way to check. Assuming you installed using the default configuration.

In `/usr/local/lib` you should have the following libraries

```
libcvaux.so -> libcvaux.so.2.0
libcvaux.so.2.0 -> libcvaux.so.2.0.0
libcvaux.so.2.0.0
libcv.so -> libcv.so.2.0
libcv.so.2.0 -> libcv.so.2.0.0
libcv.so.2.0.0
libcxcore.so -> libcxcore.so.2.0
libcxcore.so.2.0 -> libcxcore.so.2.0.0
libcxcore.so.2.0.0
libhighgui.so -> libhighgui.so.2.0
libhighgui.so.2.0 -> libhighgui.so.2.0.0
libhighgui.so.2.0.0
libml.so -> libml.so.2.0
libml.so.2.0 -> libml.so.2.0.0
libml.so.2.0.0
```

And in `/usr/local/include/opencv` you should have the following header files.

```
cvaux.h, cvcompat.h, cv.hpp, cvver.h, cvwimage.h, cxcore.hpp, cxflann.h, 
cxmisc.h, cxtypes.h, highgui.hpp, cvaux.hpp, cv.h, cvtypes.h, cvvidsurv.hpp, 
cxcore.h, cxerror.h, cxmat.hpp, cxoperations.hpp, highgui.h, ml.h
```

*I'm assuming that you using the latest version which is 2.0.*

Comment: Thanks, however I am using version 1.0. Karmic doesn't have the version 2.0 repositories.

Comment: @Sunny : Hey, I am new to openCV ..... what all projects have you done using it ?

Comment: I mostly do object detection stuffs. For example detecting number of cars in a parking lot. Right now I'm working on obstacles detecting for an intelligent vehicle.

Comment: and how can i get the version?

Comment: how to find where my opencv install in my system ? any one have idea?

Comment: always making it difficult linux

Answer (score 3):

Open your terminal and type this command:
`python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"`

This works on my system

Answer (score 2):

Here is c++ version

```
// https://www.solarianprogrammer.com/2014/04/21/opencv-beaglebone-      black-ubuntu/
// Test to check the OpenCV version
// Build on Linux with:
// g++ test_1.cpp -o test_1 -lopencv_core

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, OpenCV version "<< CV_VERSION << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dpkg`.

`$ dpkg -l | grep libopencv`

Or if you use python version:

```
$ python
>>>> import cv2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the simplest way:

`/usr/bin/opencv_version`

Comment: don't have this folder, ubuntu 16