# Find OpenCV Version Installed on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to find out what version of OpenCV is installed on my computer (i am running Ubuntu 10.04). Is there a simple way to check it if ? If not then can i find out the directories where files (samples, etc) are installed ?

I am trying to run some code that i have already tested on another computer with OpenCV 2.3 installed and i get many errors.

Comment: Open Python IDLE and type following codes
import cv2
print cv2.__version__

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can look at the headers or libs installed. pkg-config can tell you where they are:

```
pkg-config --cflags opencv
pkg-config --libs opencv
```

Alternatively you can write a simple program and print the following defs:

```
CV_MAJOR_VERSION
CV_MINOR_VERSION
```

A similar question has been also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422514/how-to-check-for-opencv):

Comment: If you don't have the development packages installed, you won't have the `.pc` files and will get an error like `Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path`, which defaults to `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/`   The `--modversion` argument is also more helpful for this particular question, as I note below.

Comment: The link you posted has a much better answer now:  "pkg-config --modversion opencv"   .Thank you for posting

Comment: It worked for me like that in C++ :

cout<<"OpenCV Version used:"<<CV_MAJOR_VERSION<<"."<<CV_MINOR_VERSION<<endl;

Comment: command I do on Debian buster 10 to check openCV version :
$ sudo python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
4.2.0

Answer (score 166):

The other methods here didn't work for me, so here's what does work in Ubuntu 12.04 'precise'.

On Ubuntu and other Debian-derived platforms, dpkg is the typical way to get software package versions.  For more recent versions than the one that @Tio refers to, use

```
 dpkg -l | grep libopencv
```

If you have the development packages installed, like `libopencv-core-dev`, you'll probably have `.pc` files and can use `pkg-config`:

```
 pkg-config --modversion opencv
```

**Update in 2023**: If you get OpenCV via Python, you can use this:

`python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"`

Comment: "pkg-config --modversion opencv" works

Comment: For opencv4 do this "pkg-config --modversion opencv4"

Comment: upvoting for **update**

Answer (score 17):

1) Direct Answer:
Try this:

```
   sudo updatedb
   locate OpenCVConfig.cmake
```

For me, I get:

```
   /home/pkarasev3/source/opencv/build/OpenCVConfig.cmake
```

To see the version, you can try:

```
   cat /home/pkarasev3/source/opencv/build/OpenCVConfig.cmake
```

giving

```
    ....
   SET(OpenCV_VERSION 2.3.1)
    ....
```

2) Better Answer:

"sudo make install" is your enemy, don't do that when you need to compile/update the library often and possibly debug step through it's internal functions. Notice how my config file is in a local build directory, not in /usr/something.   You will avoid this confusion in the future, and can maintain several different versions even (debug and release, for example).

Edit: the reason this questions seems to arise often for ***OpenCV*** as opposed to other libraries is that it changes rather dramatically and fast between versions, and many of the operations are not so well-defined / well-constrained so you can't just rely on it to be a black-box like you do for something like libpng or libjpeg. Thus, better to not install it at all really, but just compile and link to the build folder.

Comment: cat $(locate OpenCVConfig.cmake) | grep "SET(OpenCV_VERSION "

Comment: @AlanSamet comment is a perfect direct answer

Answer (score 6):

There is also a flag CV_VERSION which will print out the full version of opencv

Answer (score 2):

To install this product you can see this tutorial: [OpenCV on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV)

There are listed the packages you need. So, with:

```
# dpkg -l | grep libcv2
# dpkg -l | grep libhighgui2
```

and more listed in the url you can find which packages are installed.

With

```
# dpkg -L libcv2
```

you can check where are installed

This operative is used for all debian packages.

Comment: Dpkg is spelled wrong here, and those packages aren't in Ubuntu 12.04, so I added a different answer for the latest release.