# QT causing cv::circle() Assertion Failed when given inputs within range

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have a QT GUI for controlling a camera, and I'm using OpenCV 4.5.5 to track a circle within the video from the camera, however when I go to display the circle on the image, the `cv::circle` function displays the following error:

The code:

```
circle(binary_plus_color, Point(X_Point, Y_Point), Center_Radius, col, Thickness, LINE_8, Shift);
```

The error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.5.1) ../modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp:1884: error: (-215:Assertion failed) radius >= 0 && thickness <= MAX_THICKNESS && 0 <= shift && shift <= XY_SHIFT in function 'circle'
```

I first checked the `binary_plus_color` Mat, and it is created and displays properly when the circle code is removed.

I then checked the values of all the inputs into the function, to make sure they're within the range, which they are:

```
X_Point: 404
Y_Point: 298
Center_Radius: 1
col: Scalar(0, 255, 0)
Thickness: 1
Shift: 0
```

I tested the same code outside of QT, and the code ran as expected. I have tried calling it as `cv::circle()` to force the use of the OpenCV function, which did not solve the problem. So it appears that QT is causing the issue, but I do not know why/how.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: The full source code can be seen [here](https://github.com/cjm-64/QT-OCV-Circles).

Comment: Post your source code on GitHub.

Comment: https://github.com/cjm-64/QT-OCV-Circles

Comment: BTW, you mention you're using version 4.5.5, but the error message says 4.5.1 -- what gives?

Comment: I am not sure. I used [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.5.5.zip) link to download it, and then when I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12536170/10946580) method it shows 4.5.1. I do not know the cause unfortunately.

Comment: I had a look, and the values listed in the question are being passed into the function., so without the variables the function is `circle(binary_plus_color, Point(412, 308), 1, col, 1, LINE_8, 0);` I also tried a smaller program to test the circle issue, and I ran into more issues that are solved by taking the program out of QT.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I was unable to find a solution, but I was able to solve the issue by uninstalling OpenCV 4.5.5 and installing OpenCV 4.5.1.

Comment: Well, I know I'm being pedantic but, if you were able to solve the issue, then you *did* find a solution. Just not maybe one you particularly like. :)