# Does OpenCv have a constant with its version number?

Tags: c++, opencv, shared-libraries

I ask this because I have a couple installed and have some doubts if I am loading the right dynamic libraries.

This question is slightly different from these as they answer what is installed and not what your application is linking:

[Find OpenCV Version Installed on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8804064/1085483)

[How to check for openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2422514/1085483)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to great @berak's answer (related to [version.hpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/version.hpp)):

There are different naming schemes in OpenCV 2.4 and OpenCV 3.0 branches.
For **OpenCV 2.4.x** we have something like this (note that for **2.4.x** `CV_VERSION_MAJOR` is **4**):

```
#define CV_VERSION_EPOCH    2
#define CV_VERSION_MAJOR    4
#define CV_VERSION_MINOR    8
#define CV_VERSION_REVISION 0
```

And for **OpenCV 3.0.x** we have the following (note that `CV_VERSION_MAJOR` sense was changed!):

```
#define CV_VERSION_MAJOR    3
#define CV_VERSION_MINOR    0
#define CV_VERSION_REVISION 0
#define CV_VERSION_STATUS   "-dev"
```

That is if you need support for both **2.4.x** abd **3.0.x**, code will be slightly non-obvious if you want to check `CV_VERSION_MAJOR`.
I prefer checking `CV_VERSION_EPOCH` instead:

```
#if (defined(CV_VERSION_EPOCH) && CV_VERSION_EPOCH == 2)
# OpenCV 2.4.x stuff
#else
# OpenCV 3.0 stuff
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

there is a [version.hpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/version.hpp) header in core, which defines constants like CV_VERSION_MAJOR, etc.

apart from this, `cout << cv::getBuildInformation() << endl;` is quite useful, because it will show you the cmake output generated when building opencv (so you can see the dependancies, whether it's using ffmpeg or gstreamer, the like ..)

edit: please use CV_MAJOR_VERSION, not CV_VERSION_MAJOR, since the use of the latter is conflicting between 2.4 and master

Comment: According to the link to version.hpp you posted, `CV_MAJOR_VERSION` contains the same content as `CV_VERSION_MAJOR`. So it's not clear why one should be used over the other.

Comment: @josch `CV_VERSION_MAJOR` actually contains the minor version in opencv 2.4, `CV_MAJOR_VERSION` contains the actual major version in all versions of opencv. [version.hpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/version.hpp) from 2.4.8.

Answer (score 0):

that's the definition of OpenCV 2.4.8 from version.hpp:

```
#define CV_VERSION_EPOCH    2
#define CV_VERSION_MAJOR    4
#define CV_VERSION_MINOR    8
#define CV_VERSION_REVISION 0
```